# How to form a JSON array using 1d array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, html-table

I am making fixed header table with vertical and horizontal scroll using a [**github project**](https://github.com/meetselva/fixed-table-rows-cols).

I am able to implement the basic template. Incase when I have some hidden table headers, I need to make some changes while passing the data to `colModal` of the function. I've made those changes. But I am unable to replicate(*to match as in first fiddle*) the data sent to `colModal`.

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:40px;display:none">Head1</th>
      <th style="width:50px">Head2</th>
      <th style="width:60px">Head3</th>
      <th style="width:70px">Head4</th>
      <th style="width:80px">Head5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">1</td>
      <td >2</td>
      <td >3</td>
      <td >4</td>
      <td >5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td style="display:none">1</td>
      <td >2</td>
      <td >3</td>
      <td >4</td>
      <td >5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td style="display:none">1</td>
      <td >2</td>
      <td >3</td>
      <td >4</td>
      <td >5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td style="display:none">1</td>
      <td >2</td>
      <td >3</td>
      <td >4</td>
      <td >5</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td style="display:none">1</td>
      <td >2</td>
      <td >3</td>
      <td >4</td>
      <td >5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    return this.style.width;
  }
}).get();
var viewData = {
  thsVisible: []
};
for (var i = 0; i < listWidth.length; i++) {
  var jsonData = {
    width: listWidth[i].slice(0, -2),
    align: 'left'
  };
  viewData.thsVisible.push(jsonData);
}
console.log(viewData);
$('#mytable').fxdHdrCol({
    fixedCols:  0,
    width:     "100%",
    height:    100,
    colModal: viewData
});
```

[Template fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/rs9ym7sj/)

**colModal**

```
colModal: [{width: 30, align: 'center'},
           {width: 70, align: 'center'}, 
           {width: 200, align: 'left'}, 
           {width: 100, align: 'center'}, 
           {width: 70, align: 'center'},               
          ]
```

[Template fiddle when have hidden tds](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/rs9ym7sj/2/). In this fiddle if you observe,First `td` is hidden but it's width is applied to 2nd `td` and 2nd `td's` width to 3rd and it followed, Which I am trying to avoid using the above javascript. So I am fetching the width from inline css which are not hidden.

[Fiddle I struck with](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/vrm3j368/)

Getting an error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined`. I need to match the `viewData` with `ColModal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this Jquery

```
var listWidth = $("#mytable tr th").map(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    return this.style.width;
  }
  else{
  return "0px";
  }
}).get();
var viewData = {
  thsVisible: []
};
for (var i = 0; i < listWidth.length; i++) {
  var jsonData = {
    width: parseInt(listWidth[i].slice(0, -2)),
    align: 'left'
  };
  viewData.thsVisible.push(jsonData);
}
console.log(viewData);
$('#mytable').fxdHdrCol({
    fixedCols:  0,
    width:     "100%",
    height:    100,
    colModal: viewData.thsVisible
});
```

Hope it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `viewData` object format.

The library expects an array and you're giving an object `{ thsvisible: [] }`

try with `var viewData = [0]` and `viewData.push(jsonData);`

Comment: You need also to initialize the viewData object with the first element, so everything goes right. `var viewData = [0];`